# How to configure cxf LoggingFeature in Wildfly

Tags: logging, soap, wildfly, cxf, slf4j

We use Wildfly 26 to host soap services and set org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled=true to log the request / responses.

I wanted to mask some XML elements like

```
LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
loggingFeature.addSensitiveElementNames(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("password")));
```

as I read in the CXF documentation.

I spent hours finding a solution how to configure this in Wildly without success.
Any hints?

Kind regards

Marcus